# Hibernate one to Many insertion

Tags: mysql, hibernate

In my location table i have list of employee DO and Employee table has locationid as a foreign key ,if i try to insert location DO using ORM-insert, locationid is inserted in the location table but it is null in the employee table. please help me with this issue. thanks in advance

```
 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy ="location")    
private List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "locationid")
private Location location = null;
```

Comment: Post  code snippet how u forming employee and location objects . Make sure employee object having location object reference and location object having employee object reference

Comment: @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy ="location")  this reference i have in location Do and @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "locationid") this in Employee DO

Comment: Cascading is Correct .  Post code how u forming objects . Like  Location location=new Location();   employee.setLocation(location);   location.setEmployees(employeesList);

Comment: Please post full code of your model and any other relevant code.

Comment: @Ramesh am setting the object value in the jsp like this <form:input id="LocId" path="locationid" cssClass="form-control"
        readonly="No" />

Comment: @Ramesh before inserting into the DB am passing a location object with connection manager like this  locationRepository.persist(eManagerSmartETestDB, location);  location.locationid value is INPUN12 but location.getEmployees().get(0).getLocation() is coming as null